# How error is defined in common http library? Can data and error co-exist?

Tags: node.js, http, request, fetch

A callback function used in `http request` library usually has a parameter for `error` and 1 (or 2) more for the response content.

However, I cannot find a clear definition of the error object and the relationship between the error and response object (mainly if they can co-exist).

For Q1, my first impression is that it can be classified by the status code. If so, an error in http can only have one of two categories (client/ server)?

For Q2, I believe it makes sense in some scenario to have both. For example, it is possible a server responses a `451 Unavailable For Legal Reasons`, but still return some fields by best effort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Can data and error co-exist?"*

Yes, they can co-exist. Actually, according to [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.3) (HTTP Semantics and Content)

> 3.3.  Payload Semantics

> ...

> **Response messages with an error status code
> usually contain a payload** that represents the error condition, such
> that it describes the error state and what next steps are suggested
> for resolving it.

*"How error is defined in common http library?"*

This is HTTP library implementation logic. As anyone can develop an HTTP library, parse response payload and do whatever he/she want, the "how error is defined" question is mainly decided by library designer, and does not have a criteria to answer.

Comment: Can I assume that common http library, if not specified, defines error using status code? e.g. `express`, `spring`

Comment: @Andyk. I think that is a reasonable assumption.